# How get ages GA4 api PHP SDK

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get the ages, but when adding the user Age Bracket property to the Dimension, I get the error "Please remove userAgeBracket to make the request compatible for example. The request's dimensions & metrics are incompatible. To learn more, see https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/"

How do I make the correct request?

set dimensions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I8dJ.png)
set metrics
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6zLs.png)

Comment: Some metrics/dimensions are not compatible with others. Use https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/dimensions-metrics-explorer/ to find out which are compatible and which aren't.